# Executing command after forEach finishes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have the following function that gets executed from an `ng-click` in the HTML:

```
vm.items = [];
vm.moveItems = function() {
    angular.forEach(vm.items,
        function (item) {
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/item_move/' + item.id}
            }).then(function(response) {
                Toast.success("Successfully moved item " + item.id);
                vm.reload();
            }, function (error) {
                Toast.error("Failed to move item " + item.id, error);
            });
    });
};
```

Now, the problem is that the `vm.reload()` is executed after every successful response where in fact it would be enough if it was executed once after the entire `forEach` finishes. I'm very new to async programming in JS so would like to know what the most used way to solve this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array where you store the promises from your HTTP calls. Afterwards call the `Promise.all()` method. This allows you to do stuff when all promises are finished.

```
vm.items = [];
vm.moveItems = function() {
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach(vm.items,
        function (item) {
            promises.push($http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/item_move/' + item.id}
            }));
    });
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function() {
            vm.reload();
        });
};
```

**Edit**: Since you are using AngularJS, you can also do `$q.all()`.

Comment: Perfect! I assume this is a general JS solution. I see that Angular has a `$q` constructor for this. Is it better to use that or use a plain JS solution?

Comment: @mart1n Yes it's a JS solution added in ES6. It's also possible with `$q` (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) It's better to use `$q`.

Comment: So `s/Promise/$q/` is the only change?

Comment: @mart1n exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
vm.items = [];
vm.moveItems = function() {
var i = 0 
    angular.forEach(vm.items,
        function (item) {
            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/item_move/' + item.id}
            }).then(function(response) {
                Toast.success("Successfully moved item " + item.id);
                i++;
                if(i == vm.items.length{ // execute only when its the last loop of foreach
                     vm.reload(); 
                }

            }, function (error) {
                i++;
              if(i == vm.items.length{ // execute only when its the last loop of foreach
                     vm.reload(); 
                }
                Toast.error("Failed to move item " + item.id, error);
            });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
vm.items = [];

vm.moveItems = function() {
    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach(vm.items , function(item) {

        var promise = $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/api/item_move/' + item.id}
        }).then(function(response) {
            Toast.success("Successfully moved item " + item.id);
        }, function (error) {
            Toast.error("Failed to move item " + item.id, error);
        });

        promises.push(promise);

   });

   $q.all(promises).then(function() { vm.reload() })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the vm.reload() outside the forEach loop:

```
vm.items = [];
vm.moveItems = function() {
  this._$timeout(() => {

    angular.forEach(vm.items,
      function (item) {
        $http({
          method: 'PUT',
          url: '/api/item_move/' + item.id}
        }).then(function(response) {
          Toast.success("Successfully moved item " + item.id);
        }, function (error) {
          Toast.error("Failed to move item " + item.id, error);
        });
    });

  });

  vm.reload();
};
```

Edited to add $timeout, should give it enough time to finish the foreach loop.

Comment: I don't think this works, does it? The requests in forEach will fire off and the code will continue on to the reload before the requests have actually finished, no?

Comment: This doesn't work since the HTTP call needs some time to complete. The vm.reload() is called before the requests are finished.

Comment: Edited to add in a $timeout call, should allow for the http call to finish.